# Understanding variable with structures and pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc

I don't know what the next assigment means:

```
struct reportItem * itemCopy = (struct reportItem *) malloc(sizeof(struct reportItem))
```

Could someone explain me the assigment step by step? I really don't know what does it means.

Thanks

Comment: What part don't you understand? This is one of the most common ways to use `malloc()`, it should be explained in any textbook or tutorial.

Comment: What I don't understand is the general mean. A pointer to a struct called itemCopy is created but, what the assigment means? Okey, malloc allocate memory but what about (struct reportItem *)?

Comment: Agreed; what specifically is the issue? You get a size. You allocate that much memory. You save the location of that memory to a pointer.

Comment: The left part (before `=`) declares a variable of type `struct reportItem *`, i.e. a pointer to a `struct reportItem`. The right part allocates memory from the heap the size of a `struct reportItem` and assigns that to the variable just declared. The expression between braces, `(struct reportItem *)` is a _cast_ that tells the compiler that `malloc` returned a thing of type `struct reportItem`. The cast is not needed.

Comment: @Miguel.G That's a type cast, as any C programmer should know.

Comment: Thanks @PaulOgilvie for your explanation!!  "The cast is not needed" helped me a lot.

Comment: @Barmar,  I'm sure if I ask you something about advanced telecommunications you acts as me. Please, not all people is a C programmer, "as any normal person should know". :)

Comment: SO is for programmers to help other programmers, it's not a programming school. You're expected to learn the basics, and this is really basic.

Comment: SO: Founded in 2008, Stack Overflow is the largest, most trusted online community for developers to learn, share their knowledge, and build their careers.
Developer: A developer is an individual that builds and create software and applications.
There are many types of questions, depending skill level. Not all questions have to be "expert level" to be admissible. Have you forgotten your first questions? I'm sure you don't. Please, again, everybody wants to learn step by step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`struct reportItem` is a structure type that was previously declared. A structure in C basically is a block of data that can be read in parts, where each part has a type and a name. The first part declares a pointer `itemCopy`, which is just a variable storing a memory address. The `struct reportItem` just tells the compiler that the data at that memory address should be interpreted as a `reportItem` structure. `malloc` is a function that allocates memory to store things. You tell it how many bytes of memory you need, and it returns a pointer holding the address of the first byte of that newly allocated memory. `sizeof` returns the size, in bytes, of an object or type of object. In this case, it allocates enough memory to store one `reportItem` structure. The pointer returned from `malloc` is then casted to the declared pointer type, and `itemCopy` is assigned to hold that address.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your explanation! It is was I was looking for. With this explanation and "The cast is not needed" from Paul Ogilive everything is understood. Thanks again!!

Comment: If this answered your question, please click the check mark to indicate it.

Answer (score 2):

```
struct reportItem *itemCopy = (struct reportItem *) malloc(sizeof(struct reportItem));
//                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The cast is unnecessary and may hide an error the compiler would have caught in its absence (1)

```
struct reportItem *itemCopy = malloc(sizeof(struct reportItem));
//                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Using the type itself here may be regarded as an "accident waiting to happen" (2). It is safer to use the object itself

```
struct reportItem *itemCopy = malloc(sizeof *itemCopy);
```

So now it's a good looking statement :)

This calls the library function `malloc()` (which attempts to reserve an area of memory for the program to use) and assigns the resulting value to `itemCopy`.

It's the programmer responsability to check if `malloc()` managed to reserve the memory **before** using that memory.

```
if (itemCopy == NULL) {
    //malloc failed to reserve memory
    fprintf(stderr, "no memory.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Also the programmer is responsible to release the memory (back to the OS) once that memory is no longer required.

```
//use itemCopy
free(itemCopy);
```

---

(1) cast hides error

If there is no prototype in scope for `malloc()` the compiler assumes it returns an `int`. Then, with the cast is silently converts that illegal `int` (illegal because it is, in fact, a `void*` value) to a pointer. **The error is the absence of the `#include <stdio.h>` and the cast**. If you simply remove the cast, the compiler complains about the conversion from `int` to pointer. If you `#include <stdio.h>` and keep the cast it is redundant (and redundant is bad).

(2) using the type for determining amount of memory to allocate is an "accident waiting to happen"

The call `malloc(sizeof(struct whatever))` is an "accident waiting to happen" because it forces the programmer to change code in more than one place with a single structure change.

Let's imagine there's a `struct Car` with some properties... Later on it's decided to change part of the code to the new revamped `struct Vehicle` (while keeping the `struct Car` active). Using the type name in the `malloc()` call forces 2 changes

```
struct Vehicle *x = malloc(sizeof (struct Vehicle));
//                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ prevented accident
```

while using the object requires just one change

```
struct Vehicle *x = malloc(sizeof *x);
//                                ^^ *x is of the correct type
```

Comment: Thanks for your great explanation! I checked the first answer as the correct but with all of these answer everything is understood! Thanks again :)

Comment: What error could the compiler catch if the cast would be absent? Can you give an example?

Comment: "_Using the type itself here may be regarded as an "accident waiting to happen"_" is correct. Can you elaborate and give an example so the OP understands?

Comment: Thanks @PaulOgilvie! I'll add some notes to my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

**sizeof(struct reportItem)** returns the size taken by the data type struct reportItem

**malloc** allocates the requested bytes in this case whatever is returned by **sizeof(struct reportItem)**

**(struct reportItem *)** is used to type cast the value returned by malloc. However it is not required, you can check this for more, [do i need to cast malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

struct reportItem* ItemCopy is then assigned the base address of the casted fixed memory of the size taken by reportItem.

Comment: Thanks for your great explanation! I checked the first answer as the correct but with all of these answer everything is understood! Thanks again :)

Comment: What is "fixed memory"? Is there any other type of memory?

Comment: No. I meant it in a way that it won't be dynamic i.e its size won't change